# Conditional volatility and notation to express it

Tags: conditional-expectation, notation, volatility, conditional-variance

I'm taking a risk modelling class, and we're discussing conditional vs unconditional volatility.

We have standard volatility $\sigma = \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[r_t - \mathbb{E}(r_t)]^2}$

But what is conditional volatility?: $\sigma_t = \sqrt{\mathbb{E}_{t-1}[r_t-\mathbb{E}_{t-1}(r_t)]^2}$

What does it mean to take $\mathbb{E}_{t-1}$? Is that the same thing as taking the expectation conditional on the information set? $\mathbb{E}[r_t|I_{t-1}]$

Just a little confused where the conditional comes into the formula above. If it's not taking the conditional expectation, how does it give us conditional volatility?

Comment: "Is that the same thing as taking the expectation conditional on the information set..." yes

Comment: @Taylor, why not post this as an answer so that it can be accepted and the thread may be "finished"?

Comment: What does it mean then to take the expecation E_t, or E_{t+1}?

Comment: It's what you said: $E_t$ must be the expectation with respect to the sigma algebra established by time $t.$  Example: you are considering an asset now and evaluate the volatility of its price at, say, $5$ years.  Later, after holding it for $t=4$ years, you use the information accrued during that time to re-asses the volatility of its price at $5$ years.  One is unconditional, the other is conditional.  In effect *all* expectations are conditional; what matters is how much information they are conditioned on.